# An exercise from a Python book that is killing me - Need an idea

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

The exercise sounds like this:

`Write a function that reads a CSVfile. It should return a list of dictionaries,using the first row as key names,and each subsequent rowas values for those keys.For the data in the previous example it would return:`

`[{'name': 'George', 'address': '4312 Abbey Road', 'age': 22}, {'name': 'John', 'address': '54 Love Ave', 'age': 21}]`

Input file(csv):

```
name,address,age
George,4312 Abbey Road,22
```

My code is:

```
    with open(filename,'r',newline='') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        data = list(reader)

        # Creating keys for the dict using row[0]
        for each in data[0]:
            result[each] = 0


        for key,value in result.items():
            for each_list in data[1:]:
                for each_item in each_list:
                    result[key] = each_item
        print(result)
```

Result:

```
PS C:\Users\\Desktop> py .\test.py
{'name': '22', 'address': 0, 'age': 0}
{'name': '22', 'address': '22', 'age': 0}
{'name': '22', 'address': '22', 'age': '22'}
```

And I don't understand why is this happening. Why **each_item** keeps having only **22** ? It should be *George* then *4321 Abbey Road* and finally *22*.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem?

Comment: I think csv's [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) does exactly what you want already.

Comment: However if you did want to do it yourself you should load the first row into a list, not a dictionary, so that it's ordered: then iterate through each row by index, taking the key from your list by index and the value from your row by index.

Comment: Try printing out `data` immediately after its read. this will give you a good idea of the format you're working with. Secondly, `result` should be a list of dictionaries. Think about how you can create a fresh dictionary for each row and add it to your `result` list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read the file, line-by-line, in a variable called 'lines'.

You could do something like this:

```
[{tpl[0]:tpl[1] for tpl in zip(lines[0].split(','), line.split(','))} for line in lines[1:]]
```

What this does:

The outer-most function creates an array.
Its syntax is `[a for b in c]`
Meaning: create an array of items `a`, where each item `a` can be calculated from a value `b`, which is part of an iterable `c`

We are using that function to create an array of dictionaries.

The function one level deeper is `{k:v for y in z}`
Meaning: construct a dictionary with key `k` and value `v`, whose values can be calculates from y, which is part of an iterable `z`

And finally, the `zip` function. Which takes two iterables, and returns an iterable of their tuples.

So, from the bottom:

- take line 0 of the lines you've read (which is the header)
- zip line 0 together with every line in turn, creating an iterable of tuples
- for every line, go over this iterable of tuples, and convert it to a dictionary
- add all those dictionaries to one array